# Replace img with div php

Tags: php, image, replace, vbulletin

I am trying to replace this image

```
<img src="$post[avatarurl]" $post[avwidth] $post[avheight] alt="<phrase 1="$post[username]">$vbphrase[xs_avatar]</phrase>" border="0" />
```

using php.  Everything I can think of has resulted with nothing happening.

```
$search = '<img src="' . $post[avatarurl] . '" ' . $post[avwidth] . ' ' . $post[avheight] . 'alt="<phrase 1="' . $post[username] . '">' . $vbphrase[xs_avatar] . '</phrase>" border="0" />'; 
$replace = '<div id="drcltrav" style="background-color:'.$color.';"><span>'.strtoupper($drcltrav_lgth).'</span></div>';
$vbulletin->templatecache['postbit'] = str_replace($search, $replace, $vbulletin->templatecache['postbit']);
```

also have tried

```
$search = '<img src="$post[avatarurl]" $post[avwidth] $post[avheight] alt="<phrase 1="$post[username]">$vbphrase[xs_avatar]</phrase>" border="0" />';
```

and a few other ways with no results.

another thing is the img may not always be set up like that, but it should start with

```
<img src="$post[avatarurl]"
```

is there a way to replace everything in between? like

```
<img src="$post[avatarurl]" ******* />
```

replaced with

```
<div id="myDiv">content</div>
```

Comment: why do you want to do this with php ?

Comment: because I don't know of any other way.  Obviously I don't know the php way either though -_-

Comment: Consider using [DomDocument](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). In particular, look at [loadHTML](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php), [getElementsByTagName](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php), and [saveHTML](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php). This might give you something to start with.

Answer (score 1):

I used preg_replace, see if it suits you:

```
$string='<b>sample text</b><img src="mypic.jpg" class="some" alt="">
 <p>Another paragraph</p> 
 Another picture: <img src="mypic.jpg" class="other class" border="0">';

$pattern = '/<img src="mypic.jpg"(.*?)>/';
$replacement = '<div id="myDiv">content</div>';

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Output:

```
<b>sample text</b><div id="myDiv">content</div> 
<p>Another paragraph</p> 
Another picture: <div id="myDiv">content</div>
```